# Countdown playing Alarm

Tags: android, alarm, countdowntimer

I really hope you can help me here. Below is a section of my code that successfully runs two count down timers side by side...all I want to do is play a short mp3 file when count down has finished....I have tried many different bits of code but I am struggling to make anything work...an quick wins would be good..

So to round up two timers each need to play sound when finished..

```
//Declare Start/Stop button
Button btnstart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
Button Button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);

final TextView mCounter1TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter1);
final TextView mCounter2TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter2);

//Counter 1
final CountDownTimer Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(9000000 , 1000) {
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    mCounter1TextField.setText(" " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
}

public void onFinish() {
    start();
}

};

//Counter 2
final CountDownTimer counter2 = new CountDownTimer(9000000 , 1000) {
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
  mCounter2TextField.setText(" " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));

}

public void onFinish() {
  start();
}


};

//Start Button1
btnstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
  Counter1.start();

   }
});

//Start Button2
 Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
 counter2.start();
```

Thanks in advance

Dj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `start()` is the function you call to play the sound, right ?

so inside the definition of `start()`, put the following code :

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound); //replace 'sound' by your music/sound
mp.start();
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** *trying to be super clear :)*

Somewhere in your code, it is written :

```
public void onFinish() {
    start();
}
```

This method/function is called when the counter finishes.
Inside this function it is written 'start()'

I don't know what this `start()` does.

In both cases, I suggest you keep it (if it doesn't create an error), and after `start()`,  add `playSound()` inside the two `onFinish()` methods.

and then write OUTSIDE of this function, the following:

```
public void playSound() {

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound); //replace 'sound' by your    music/sound
mp.start();

}
```

Comment: inside the definition of start()? could expand a little i am very new to coding :) Thanks

Comment: I edited and expanded my answer a lot for you :P Read it, and if you still don't understand, I'm very happy to explain to you even more, just tell me what you don't understand exactly

Comment: One further question, how do i get a button to select whether or not the alarm (playSound) goes off?